# Logical formulation of an equality

Tags: logic

**Definition (A)**: Given integers $a$ and $b$, then there exist $r=r(a,b)$ such that $r(a,b)=card(C)$ where $C$ is a given set of functions and $card$ is the number of elements of this set.

**Definition (B)**: Given integers $a$ and $b$, then there exist $m=m(a,b)$ such that $m(a,b)=degree(P)$ where $P$ is a given polynomial.

These definitions has no importance here since the question is about logic.

The function $r=r(a,b)$ verifying **Definition (A)** if and only if there exists positive integers $x,y$ such that $$r(a,b)=g(a,b,r(a,b),x,y)$$

The function $m=m(a,b)$ verifying **Definition (B)** if and only if for all $ε>0$ there exists positive real number $δ>0$ such that for all $s∈(-δ,δ)$ there exist $t∈(0,1)$ such that $$m(a,b)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t)$$

Now, I want to reformulate a logical case for the equality $$r(a,b)=m(a,b)$$ for all integers $a$ and $b$.

My **solution**:

For all integers $a$ and $b$ there exists positive integers $x,y$ and for all $ε>0$ there exists positive real number $δ>0$ such that for all $s∈(-δ,δ)$ there exist $t∈(0,1)$ such that $$g(a,b,r(a,b),x,y)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t)$$

Comment: Assuming that in Df A variables $x,y$ stand for integers $a,b$, where are $a,b$ in DEF B ?

Comment: The definitons you give define not single integer numbers, but integer-valued functions (because $r$ and $m$ are dependednt on $a$ and $b$). Therefore integer numbers cannot satisfy them -  the theorems that you give later cannot be true. You need to phrase your theorems in a way "Function $r$ satisfies (**not verifies!**) definition A if and only if (...)". In that theorem probably there will be somewhere some quantifiers regarding parametrs $a$ and $b$. We need to know what they are.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: No, $x,y$ are not $a,b$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: See my solution.

Comment: Ok, a question that follow your edits of a questions. Do the theorems that you've written are satisfied for any $a,b$? Or, for example, do you mean that there exist $a,b$ such that $r$ statisfies definition A if and only if (...)"?

Comment: Also, in your solution, do you really mean "there exist positive integers $x,y$ and (...)" or did you mean "there exist positive integers $x,y$ such that (...)"?

Comment: @AdamLatosiński: for all $a,b$.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński: I mean such that.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński: It is the first sentence.

Comment: Still unclear. Is the first theorem $$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \forall\hat r\in\mathbb{Z}_+: \big((\hat r= g(a,b, \hat r, x,y) ) \Leftrightarrow (\hat r=r(a,b))\big)$$ or $$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \forall\hat r\in\mathbb{Z}_+: \big((\hat r= g(a,b, \hat r, x,y) ) \Leftrightarrow (\hat r=r(a,b))\big) $$ or something else? Similarily for the second theorem. Please write your theorems fully, withoput skipping any quantifiers, and, if possible, with mathematical notation, so that there would be no doubt.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński: It is: for all $a,b$ there exist $r,x,y$  such that $r=...$

Comment: Please clarify it in your question.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński: See the edited question.

Comment: They are still not proper theorems. They use symbols $a$ and $b$ without mentioning what they are. It wouldn't be a problem if they were set numbers, but they are not, eventually you ask about something to be satisfied for all possible $a$ and $b$. Similiarily, as I noted before $r$ is not an integer. Only $r(a,b)$ is an integer. Please make appropriate corrections.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński: OK. Done.

Comment: It's not. I've pointed out several problems, you adressed one, and incorrectly at that. My suggestion how it should be fixed: "Function $r$ satisfies Definition $A$ if and only if for all integer $a$ and $b$ there exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that (...)". If this is what you mean, please write it like that. If it's not, then I don't know what you mean. Similarily with the second definition

Comment: Another thing you may mean is "Function r satisfies Definition A if and only if  there exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that for all integer $a$ and $b$ (...)". My problem is that it is a different theorem than the previous one and the consequences are significant. The placement of quantifiers matter, and you refuse to write them down.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński: In fact I am not understanding what you say. Can you make an edit on the question and I will review it.

Comment: There would be alot to change, so I decided to assume and write down my interpreatation in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to interpret your question in a way that I think is precise and that's what I suggest:

**Definition (A)**: For integers $a$ and $b$, let the function $r:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z \ni (a,b)\mapsto r(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ be defined as the cardinality of a given set set of functions $C_{a,b}$, that is $r(a,b)=|C_{a,b}|$.

**Definition (B)**: For integers $a$ and $b$, let the function $m:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z \ni (a,b)\mapsto m(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ be defined as the degree of a given polynomial $P_{a,b}$, that is $m(a,b)=\deg P_{a,b}$.

These definitions have no importance here since the question is about logic - we only need that $r$ and $m$ are some defined functions of integers $a$ and $b$.

Let's assume that we have function $g:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that the following theorem is true:

**Theorem 1:** The function $r$ defined by **Definition (A)** is the only function $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_+$ that satisfies the condition:
$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z : r(a,b)=g(a,b,r(a,b),x,y)$$

Let's also assume that we have function $h:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}\times(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ such that the following theorem is true:

**Theorem 2:** The function $m$ defined by **Definition (B)** is the only function $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_+$ that satisfies the condition:
$$ \forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists \delta >0 \,\forall s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\exists t \in (0,1) \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z} : m(a,b)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t)$$

Now, we want to formulate a condition for the equality of functions $r$ and $m$ that is $$ \forall a,b\in\mathbb Z:r(a,b)=m(a,b)$$

If that is the problem you pose (I'm not sure, especially because the placement of the quantifiers $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ may be different in your theorems; I've chosen this placement because they give stronger conditions - for example $\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z: {\rm condition}(a,b,x,y)$ is a stronger condition than $\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z\,\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+: {\rm condition}(a,b,x,y)$ because in the first case I require existence of $x$ an $y$ good for all possible $a$ and $b$, and in the second for any $a$ and $b$ the values of $x$ and $y$ may be different), then the solution is as follows.

For future reference, let us denote the set of functions $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_+$ as $\mathcal F$.

Let us define two conditions that can be applied on functions $f\in\mathcal F$:

**Condition 1**: 
$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z : f(a,b)=g(a,b, f(a,b),x,y)$$

**Condition 2**: 
$$ \forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists \delta >0 \,\forall s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\exists t \in (0,1) \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z} : f(a,b)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t)$$

**Theorem 1** says that **Condition 1** is satisfied if and only if $f=r$, and **Theorem 2** says that **Condition 2** is satisfied if and only if $f=m$.

The condition $r=m$ means that there exists a function that satisfies both of these conditions at once. And of course, if ther exists a function that satisfies both conditions at once, then because each condition is only satsfied by one function $r$ and $m$ respectively, it means that $r=m$.

Therefore the condition $r=m$ is equivalent to condition
$$\exists f\in\mathcal F: \Big(\big(\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z : f(a,b)=g(a,b,f(a,b),x,y)\big) \land \big(\forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists \delta >0 \,\forall s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\exists t \in (0,1) \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z} : f(a,b)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t)\big)\Big) $$

It can be rewriten as 
$$\exists f\in\mathcal F \,\forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists \delta >0 \,\forall s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\exists t \in (0,1) \,\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+\,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z\,\forall a',b'\in\mathbb{Z} : \Big( \big(f(a,b)=g(a,b,f(a,b),x,y)\big) \land \big(f(a',b')=h(a',b',ε,δ,s,t)\big)\Big) $$
which can be simplified to 
$$\exists f\in\mathcal F  \,\forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists \delta >0 \,\forall s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\exists t \in (0,1) \,\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+\,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z : \Big( f(a,b)=g(a,b,f(a,b),x,y)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t) \Big)$$

As an implication (therefore a necessary condition) one can deduce that
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists \delta >0 \,\forall s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\exists t \in (0,1) \,\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+\,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z :  \Big(g(a,b,h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t),x,y)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t) \Big)$$
It is also a sufficient condition, because the condition 
$$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+\,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z :  g(a,b,h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t),x,y)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t) $$
is equivalent (by Theorem 1) to
$$ \forall a,b\in\mathbb Z :  r(a,b)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t) $$
so the existance of some function $f\in\mathcal F$ is guaranteed (this function is $f=r$).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still unclear, but your solution isn't even a proper logical sentence. What you've written is (in mathematical notation)

$$ \forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z} : \Big((\exists x,y\in\mathbb Z_+) \land \big(\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall s\in(-\delta,\delta)\exists t\in(0,1) :g(a,b,r(a,b),x,y)=h(a,b,\epsilon,\delta,s,t)\big)\Big)$$

or (there's some ambiguity about the placement of brackets caused by using natural language)

$$ \big(\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \exists x_,y\in\mathbb Z_+ \big)\land \Big(\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall s\in(-\delta,\delta)\exists t\in(0,1) :g(a,b,r(a,b),x,y)=h(a,b,\epsilon,\delta,s,t)\Big)$$

neither sentence is a proper logical sequence, because the logical operator "and" separated quantifier $\forall x,y$ from the functions that use variables $x,y$.