# Negation of a complicated logical case

Tags: logic

The motivtion to this uestion can be found in the first answer of this question ([Logical formulation of an equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3595643/logical-formulation-of-an-equality))

I want find a logical negation of the this case:

$$\exists f\in\mathcal F  \,\forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists \delta >0 \,\forall s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\exists t \in (0,1) \,\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z, \exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+\ : \Big( f(a,b)=g(a,b,f(a,b),x,y)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t) \Big)$$

I know about the satandard negation which is:

$$\forall f\in\mathcal F  \,\exists \epsilon >0 \,\forall \delta >0 \,\exists s \in (-\delta,\delta)\,\forall t \in (0,1) \,\exists a,b\in\mathbb Z, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+\ : \Big( f(a,b)≠h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t) \Big)$$

But I have some doubts about this formulation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the context of your question, in particular I ignore the meaning of the functions $g$ and $h$. 
Anyway in the sentence that you want to negate, 
\begin{align}
f(a,b)=g(a,b,f(a,b),x,y)=h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t)
\end{align}
means 
\begin{align}
f(a,b)=g(a,b,f(a,b),x,y) \land f(a,b) =h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t).
\end{align}
Therefore, its negation is
\begin{align}
f(a,b) \neq g(a,b,f(a,b),x,y) \lor f(a,b) \neq h(a,b,ε,δ,s,t)
\end{align}

The rest of your negation is correct.